# Role of class diagram in real world system implementation

Tags: oop, uml, class-diagram

I have designed the domain models of my system by using class diagram. It only includes the business domain logic of my system but not application logic that will be affected by the choice of platform, tools and programming language. This is all right in the analysis stage because no implementation detail is required yet.

However, I found that the class diagram that I have designed in the analysis stage is not sufficient to be used as the blueprint to develop the system in the implementation stage due to the lack of application logic, presentation logic and persistence logic details. Do I need to re-design the class diagram or create another type of diagram to serve as the blueprint for implementation?

I did not have any real world experiences in designing and implementing a system from the start to end so I would like to have some insights on the role of class diagram in real world system development.

The book - **Applying Use Case Driven Object Modeling with UML** has defined analysis-level class diagram as the class diagram that includes domain models while design-level class diagram is the class diagram that is "closer" to the source code implementation. However, I could not find any example of design-level class diagram and do not know what should be included in the design-level class diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be a long story, so I try to make it short. You were so far only on a certain level of abstraction. But once you reach the borders you need to extend your model. A good way it the use of Model Driven Architecture ([MDA](http://www.omg.org/mda/)). Here you introduce 3 layers called

- **CIM** Computation Independent Model,
- **PIM** Platform Independent Model and
- **PSM** Platform Specific Model

While the CIM only looks a requirements and use cases and talks about business the PIM concretes this layer and forms classes (the level you were looking at). Finally the PSM models concrete things as hardware where the system will be deployed.

There are quite a number of different processes which deal with creation of such a model. I once made a good start with [ICONIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICONIX) but [RUP](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_Unified_Process) is also widely used (though much more complex).

Comment: Your answer is really helpful and clarified my doubts. Just to ensure that I have gotten your point correctly - my current domain model class diagram can be considered as PIM and additional PSM class diagram will be required to form the basis for the system implementation. Did I get it correctly?

Comment: Exactly. Quite some time ago I had been at the same stage as you. What I did was to shift my stuff into PIM and add CIM/PSM. Some tools provide transformation from high abstraction to the next concrete level. But I prefer to use manual <<trace>> relations.